# Free Hosted Project Planners That Aren't Iterative

Tags: project-management, trac, hosted, pivotaltracker

I am currently using Pivotal Tracker and I like it for its features. The project I am working on though is basically just a hobby game project on the side (even though I plan to sell it when I am done). So while I do want to advance and work on it in a timely matter, I really don't feel like being "timed" with iterations like Pivotal Tracker does.

I really like Trac, but I don't want to host it on my home server because I don't run that server 24/7 and I have another person working on the project that doesn't have access to my server. So I want that person to be able to access the tracker at all times. So are there any project trackers like Trac that are hosted?

Thanks

Comment: This should probably be on webapps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a good tracker called Acunote ([http://www.acunote.com](http://acunote.com)). It is really good, and free for my project requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/) can do what you want.  Free hosting with issue tracking, etc.

Comment: But my project isn't open source. I don't want to make the code public. Isn't SourceForge an open source hosting site?

Answer (score 0):

Check out something like Assembla. For a relatively low price, they'll have issue tracking, SVN hosting, and even a simple wiki.